# Why are save and restore used when tinting this image?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I found this code to tint an canvas image file. I'm wondering what ist ctx.save and ctx.restore is used for in this tinting context? Why is it needed here?

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Yqg2Y/)**

```
        function recolor(color) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(pic, 0, 0);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        return (img);
    }
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/canvas_states.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save` and `restore` are used to save and restore all context state, such as `fillStyle`, `lineWidth`, `globalCompositeOperation`, the clipping region, the current context transformation matrix, and so on.

The only necessary purpose of the `save` and `restore` in your fiddle is to reset the `globalCompositeOperation`.

You can do this manually instead:

```
    function recolor(color) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(pic, 0, 0);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fill();

        //instead of save and restore:
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        return (img);
    }
```

In general you should avoid using `save` and `restore` unless you absolutely must, as it can get computationally expensive.

Answer (score 0):

ctx save and restore are used to save the current context state.  This is commonly used in functions so that you can call them anywhere and not worry that it will change the draw state outside of the function.

So for instance, in this code you change the fillStyle.  Once ctx.restore is called, the fill style will return to what it was when the ctx.save was called.